# Change DateTime format of OWIN .expiration and .issued dates

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I started with the "Individual User Accounts" authentication option when creating a .NET Web API starter template (as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)). The token is being correctly generated, however the ".issued" and ".expires" property are in a non-ISO date format. How do I format them with [`DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip) so it's ISO 8601 compliant?

```
{
  "access_token": "xxx",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 1199,
  "userName": "foo@bar.com",
  "Id": "55ab2c33-6c44-4181-a24f-2b1ce044d981",
  ".issued": "Thu, 13 Aug 2015 23:08:11 GMT",
  ".expires": "Thu, 13 Aug 2015 23:28:11 GMT"
}
```

The template uses a custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and provides a hook to add additional properties to the outgoing token (the 'Id' and 'userName' are my props), but I don't see any way to change existing properties.

I did notice that in the override of[`TokenEndpoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserverprovider.tokenendpoint(v=vs.113).aspx), I get a `OAuthTokenEndpointContext` that has a properties dictionary with the .issued and .expired keys. Trying to change these values, however, has no effect.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Is there is any issue that you are facing if the time is not passed in ISO format? I think you need to customer JSON.Net Serialize to serialize date types to ISO by default

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`AuthenticationProperties` class is defined in `Microsoft.Owin.Security` namespace in Microsoft.Owin.dll.

The setter of `IssuedUtc` property does the following (for `ExpiresUtc` is similar):

```
this._dictionary[".issued"] = value.Value.ToString("r", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As you can see, when setting the `IssuedUtc` the `.issued` field of dictionary is set too, and with ["r" format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can try to do the following in the `TokenEndPoint` method:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
{
    if (property.Key == ".issued")
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, context.Properties.IssuedUtc.Value.ToString("o", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    else if (property.Key == ".expires")
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, context.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value.ToString("o", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    else
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Unbelievable that MS don't send dates in a format that everyone can understand! Especially for something as important as authentication!!

Comment: @MattSkeldon you mean like RFC1123?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Super useful answer, saved me a few hours.